# why the real time SQL monitor in sql developer(oracle) turns me no selection? What are the steps to see the performance metrics in sql developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-administration

why the real time SQL monitor in sql developer(oracle) turns me no selection? What are the steps to see the performance metrics in sql developer?

[image]

Comment: Can you ask 4th time same questions?

Comment: Look at the queries we're running in the Log panel, ask your dba for privs on those views and stored procedures

Comment: @MarkoIvkovic the stackoverflow didn't give me to ask question because of its short length, thats why I pasted it for second time, is there any problem with that?

Comment: Can you please read article about [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @MarkoIvkovic all the other users understood my question, that means there is no problem with my quetion, ok? bb

Comment: Hello @dere, please consider providing more explanation for your question. The title of the question is either grammatically wrong or not clear enough.  please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to ask a good question. Remember good question attracts answers easily.

Answer (score 0):

Before Oracle 19c, you had to have SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE role, but it doesn't require now:
https://www.thegeekdiary.com/real-time-sql-monitoring-for-developers-oracle-database-19c-new-feature/

Comment: how can I give this role?

Answer (score 0):

I understood that real time SQL monitor turns me no selection because I used 11g express edition that is free version of oracle sql. I think that it is not free to use this software, to use it we have to download enterprise edition. I am not sure but I think so.